# iOS restore state issue

Tags: ios

I recently upgraded my old iPhone app and the new state restore iOS 3/4 feature has introduced a problem.  I don't know the name of this restore state feature - what is it called?

Here is my problem scenario:
I navigate into a detail screen on my app.  I click a button to navigate to an address and it launches google maps as expected.  Then I launch my app again.  It briefly shows the last screen I was on, but immediately launches the google map again.

What I want is to simply restore the detail screen that I was last on.

Any hints?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called multitasking, and it is built in automatically when you build under iOS 4.0+.  Without you posting any code, it is tough so say, but why don't you put a breakpoint at the line that redirects to Google Maps and see what is calling it. Then you can backtrack to see why it is being called on the reopening of the app.